# Permutations of a numpy array into an ndarray or matrix

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, permutation

```
foo = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

I have a numpy array `foo` that I would like to transform into an ndarry or a matrix, similar to this:

```
bar = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[3,4,1,2],[4,1,2,3]])
```

Any suggestions on how to do this efficiently, as my source array `foo` will vary in size, and I'll need to do this transformation millions of times.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `np.roll` in a loop.

```
x = np.array([np.roll(foo, -x) for x in np.arange(foo.shape[0])])

print(x)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 1],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [4, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 3):

For a massive performance we could  incorporate [`strides`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) here. The trick is to concatenate the original array with the sliced array ending at the second last element and then taking sliding windows of lengths same as the length of the original array.

Hence, the implementation would be -

```
def strided_method(ar):
    a = np.concatenate(( ar, ar[:-1] ))
    L = len(ar)
    n = a.strides[0]
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (L,L), (n,n), writeable=False)
```

The output would be read-only and a view of the concatenated array and as such would have a constant time almost irrespective of the array size. This means a hugely efficient solution. If you need writable output with its own memory space, make a copy there, as shown in the timings later on.

Sample run -

```
In [51]: foo = np.array([1,2,3,4])

In [52]: strided_method(foo)
Out[52]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 1],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [4, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [53]: foo = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000))

# @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's loopy soln
In [54]: %timeit np.array([np.roll(foo, -x) for x in np.arange(foo.shape[0])])
100 loops, best of 3: 12.7 ms per loop

In [55]: %timeit strided_method(foo)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.46 µs per loop

In [56]: %timeit strided_method(foo).copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 454 µs per loop
```

Comment: Was waiting for you to post!

Answer (score 2):

These matrices are called Hankel matrices. Most platforms offer already a specific routine for creating them. You can also implement yourself by removing the unnecessary parts to increase speed. It's [a pretty concise code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/linalg/special_matrices.py#L246)

```
from scipy.linalg import hankel

A = hankel([1,2,3,4], [4,1,2,3])
A
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 1],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [4, 1, 2, 3]])
```

It seems that it's only ~2x slower than Divakar's solution which is surprisingly fast.